# push message from socket into django channels

Tags: django, sockets, django-channels

I have an python socket running, that devices can send data to. I want to save the data and display it to users using django. How would i forward / push the data to django using django channels. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways Django can receive the message from other like your devices.

1. Once is your device can talk POST or GET to Django server and you'll get the data
2. Start a new thread in your Django (because now it support async.) and you can receive the socket data and update the user.